# URI not absolute calling microservice in kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices, minikube

I've developed a microservice which responds at:

```
http://localhost:8080/aggregator?email=myemail@email.com
```

when I run it into a **Kubernetes** deployment (with Minikube) and using the load-balancer service in order to expose the service outside, I'm not able to reach it.

So doing:

```
minikube service aggregator --url
```

gives me back

```
http://192.168.99.100:32482
```

But on Postman if I do the GET request:

```
http://192.168.99.100:32482/aggregator?email=myemail@email.com
```

I get the following error:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2018-09-05T15:32:58.269+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "URI is not absolute",
  "path": "/"
}
```

If I try with this:

```
http://192.168.99.100:32482/aggregator/#?email=myemail@email.com
```

it recognize it needs the query param 'email' but doesn't recognize it, because it gives me back:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2018-09-05T15:40:23.453+0000",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Required String parameter 'email' is not present",
  "path": "/aggregator/"
}
```

What am I missing?